# Importing Existing PhoneGap to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I'm having an issue importing my PhoneGap project into Eclipse. I imported my project using the existed android code option but when I import, I am receiving hundreds of errors. My build will not run because of this. I believe it is trying to call in Cordova Library that isn't found but I have included it in my project. Can anyone assist me with this problem?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/aeQZ8rq.png]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Eclipse doesn't even recognize your projet as an Android projet. 
Check if your projet use Android SDK.
I had the some similar issues with Eclipse, then I moved to [Intellij IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and that mostly solved all my problems.